# Sum up vector values till threshold, then start again

Tags: arrays, matlab, cumsum

I have a vector `a = [1 3 4 2 1 5 6 3 2]`. Now I want to create a new vector 'b' with the `cumsum` of `a`, but after reaching a threshold, let's say 5, `cumsum` should reset and start again till it reaches the threshold again, so the new vector should look like this:

```
b = [1 4 4 2 3 5 6 3 5]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Dou you have only integers?

Comment: no, i also have non-integers like 0.987

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a loop. You create the first cumulative sum `cs`, and then as long as elements in `cs` are larger than your threshold `th`, you replace them with elements from the cumulative sum on the rest of the elements in `a`.

Because some elements in `a` might be larger than `th`, this loop will be infinite unless we also eliminate these elements too.

Here is a simple solution with a `while` loop:

```
a = [1 3 4 2 1 5 6 3 2];
th = 5;
cs = cumsum(a);
while any(cs>th & cs~=a) % if 'cs' has values larger that 'th',
                       % and there are any values smaller than th left in 'a'
    % sum all the values in 'a' that are after 'cs' reached 'th',
    % excluding values that are larger then 'th'
    cs(cs>th & cs~=a) = cumsum(a(cs>th & cs~=a));
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You could build a sparse matrix that, when multiplied by the original vector, returns the cumulative sums. I haven't timed this solution versus others, but I strongly suspect this will be the fastest for large arrays of a.

```
% Original data
a = [1 3 4 2 1 5 6 3 2];
% Threshold
th = 5;
% Cumulative sum corrected by threshold
b = cumsum(a)/th;
% Group indices to be summed by checking for equality,
% rounded down, between each cumsum value and its next value. We add one to
% prevent NaNs from occuring in the next step. 
c = cumsum(floor(b) ~= floor([0,b(1:end-1)]))+1;
% Build the sparse matrix, remove all values that are in the upper
% triangle.
S = tril(sparse(c.'./c == 1));
% In case you use matlab 2016a or older:
% S = tril(sparse(bsxfun(@rdivide,c.',c) == 1));
% Matrix multiplication to create o.
o = S*a.';
```

Answer (score 1):

By normalizing the arguments of [**`cumsum`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) with the threshold and flooring you can get grouping indizes for [**`accumarray`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html), which then can do the `cumsum`ming groupwise:

```
t = 5;
a = [1 3 4 2 1 5 6 3 2];

%// cumulative sum of normalized vector a 
n = cumsum(a/t);
%// subs for accumarray
subs = floor( n ) + 1;
%// cumsum of every group
aout = accumarray( subs(:), (1:numel(subs)).', [], @(x) {cumsum(a(x))});
%// gather results;
b = [aout{:}]
```

Comment: Nice one, I should definitly learn how to use `accumarray` to its full potential

Answer (score -1):

Calculate the cumulative sum and replace the indices value obeying your condition.

```
 a = [1 3 4 2 1 5 6 3 2] ;

 b = [1 4 4 2 3 5 6 3 5] ;

 iwant = a ;
 a_sum = cumsum(a) ;
 iwant(a_sum<5) = a_sum(a_sum<5) ;
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me...After reaching the threshold for the first time the rest of the new vector get's summed up above threshold...

Comment: Ohhh..yes. .I missed it.. will get back tomorrow...:)